# VBA Pivot Chart data labels not appear

Tags: vba, excel, charts, pivot

Currently I'm trying to appear the data labels for my Pivot Chart. I don't know why it do not appear as expected. Here is my coding :

```
Sub Dimmaer()
    Sheets("Closed INC Table").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select)
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
End Sub
```

Here is what I got :
[image]

Meanwhile it should be appear like this :
[image]

Note that I don't know the Range for the tables coz the row will change from time to time.
How can I solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could manually force the data labels rather than relying on the chart style to include them on creation

```
Sub Dimmaer()
    Sheets("Closed INC Table").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address)
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).ApplyDataLabels   '<~~ This
    'optionally set position
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).ApplyDataLabels   '<~~ And this
    'optionally set position
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionCenter
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelCenter)
End Sub
```

If the data labels were already part of the chart these will have no effect; e.g. they will not get toggled off.

Comment: Sorry @Jeeped ,  I try to execute your code by copy paste the entire code but nothing change.

Comment: Were you getting an error on your original code `Range(Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select)`? I've corrected it above.